# Spring - Rabbitmq Listener needs to paused and resumed during database change

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

Hey The requirement is to pause the rabbitmq listeners from processing messages during a change to the backend tables. This change is limited to just my application so don't want to bring down the entire rabbitmq instance. Once the process is complete I want to kickstart the listeners again.

**Issue I'm facing**
I have 2 listeners connected to 2 separate queues sharing a 'consumerconnectionFactory'. When I killed the connection, only the one without any open channels get killed and when I resumed the connection I got an extra connection which was not there earlier. **Can you please help.**

I'm sharing my java configs below.

```
@Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer auditMessageListenerContainer(AuditMessageListener auditMessageListener)
    {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(consumerConnectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(messagingAuditQueue);
        container.setMessageListener(auditMessageListener);
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        container.setMissingQueuesFatal(false);
        container.setForceCloseChannel(true);
        container.setExclusive(false);
        return container;
    }
    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageListenerContainer accessMessageListenerContainer(AccessLogListener accessLogListener)
    {
        SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(consumerConnectionFactory);
        container.setQueueNames(accessAuditQueue);
        container.setMessageListener(accessLogListener);
        container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(5);
        container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.AUTO);
        container.setDefaultRequeueRejected(false);
        container.setMissingQueuesFatal(false);
        container.setForceCloseChannel(true);
        container.setExclusive(false);
        return container;
    }
```

This is how I did the Java config for the Listeners.

Below is the RestController to start and stop the listeners

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(MESSAGE_AUDIT_ROOT)
public class RestartController {
    @Autowired
    private List<MessageListenerContainer> listenerContainers;

    @Autowired
    private List<ConnectionFactory> connectionFactories;

    @GetMapping("/stop")
    public String stopMessageListenerContainer() {
        connectionFactories.forEach(conFactory -> {
            CachingConnectionFactory cConFactory = (CachingConnectionFactory) conFactory;
            cConFactory.resetConnection();
        });
        listenerContainers.forEach(container -> {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer smlc = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) container;
            smlc.shutdown();
        });
        listenerContainers.forEach(container -> System.out
                .println("Container: " + container.toString() + "is Running ?" + container.isRunning()));
        return "done - stop";
    }

    @GetMapping("/start")
    public String startMessageListenerContainer() {
        connectionFactories.forEach(conFactory -> {
            CachingConnectionFactory cConFactory = (CachingConnectionFactory) conFactory;
            cConFactory.createConnection();
        });
        listenerContainers.forEach(container -> {
            SimpleMessageListenerContainer smlc = (SimpleMessageListenerContainer) container;
            smlc.start();
        });
        listenerContainers.forEach(container -> System.out
                .println("Container: " + container.toString() + "is Running ?" + container.isRunning()));
        return "done - start";
    }

}
```

Below is the Images for the behavior I see locally.
1. Initial connections list
[image: Initial connections list]

2. When Connection stop Rest call
   [image]

2.1 Queue connection still active
[image]
3. When connection start Rest Call
[image]

Comment: What version of spring-rabbit are you using? You also need to show your connection factory configuration.

Comment: its 2.0.12.RELEASE, the connection factor configuration is from a common internal jar which uses xml configuration 
`<!-- RabbitMQ Connection Factory for Consumers-->
 <rabbit:connection-factory id="consumerConnectionFactory" host="${messaging.server}" port="${messaging.port}" username="${messaging.username}" password="${messaging.password}" connection-name-strategy="connectionName" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the default cache mode (CHANNEL), there should only be one connection at all times, unless you configure a `RabbitTemplate` with `usePublisherConnection` set to true, in which case, the connection name would be `api-audit.publisher`.

Since you have two connections with the name `api-audit`, there is something very odd going on. I suspect you somehow have two connection factories loaded, perhaps one is in a child application context? You can't have two beans with the same name in a single application context.

i.e. you are calling `resetConnection` on one of them but not the other.

I suggest you put a breakpoint in `createConnection` to see who's using a second CF.

By the way, you should really reset the connection after the container is stopped; otherwise the container will go into recovery mode and might re-open the connection, depending on timing.

Comment: Hey @Garry Russell Thanks for input I was able to look into my code and found that there is a parent context build with the same number of beans, I missed this because part of my code base is in xml and remaining half in java config. I fixed this and included ur recommendation of stopping the listeners before resetConnection and everything worked really good. Thanks :)